# Unable to mount usb disk drive through command

Tags: usb, mount

I am running Ubuntu Focal(20.04.5 LTS) on a laptop.

A usb drive containing ext4 fileysystem is recognizable through the lsblk command

```
$ lsblk
...
sda           8:0    1  14.9G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    1  14.9G  0 part
...
```

Attempt to mount it through command line fails without any error

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ mount | grep /mnt
$ ls /mnt
$ sudo umount /mnt
umount: /mnt: not mounted.
```

To be able to successfully mount and use the usb drive, I have to launch the File Manager GUI and click on the label corresponding to the usb drive. At this point I can see the drive mounted and available to use at the path of /media/<login_name>/<drive_label>

There are times, I cannot physically get to the laptop to launch the File Manager.
Need assistance on how to get the drive to mount through command line.

Comment: create `mkdir /media/myusb` and mount with `sudo  mount -t ext4  /dev/sda1 /media/myusb`

Comment: That works. what's wrong with my previous commands.

Comment: Your original command works for me and *should* work. What is the output of `ls -ld /mnt` and `ls -l /mnt`? Could there be some missing identifier in that particular ext4 file system, so that you need the option `-t` of `mount`?

Comment: $ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ ls -ld /mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  9  2021 /mnt
$ ls -l /mnt
total 0

Comment: @user3477071, Thanks for those details.  The output of `ls -ld /mnt` and `ls -l /mnt` look like they should (when nothing is mounted there). So for some strange reason you cannot mount there, but you can mount on a subdirectory of `/media`.

Comment: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdxy` Sorry for my wrong last comment; my keyboard is damaged.